# Was the { Levels:n } beacon tag removed/altered in Minecraft Java 1.14?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to run a command if a nether star is two blocks above a fully powered beacon. In 1.13, the following command worked:

```
execute as @e[type=item,nbt={Item:{id:"minecraft:nether_star",Count:1b,tag:{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"Catalyst\",\"color\":\"yellow\"}"}}}}] at @s if block ~ ~-2 ~ minecraft:beacon{Levels:4} run say success
```

However, in 1.14, it doesn't. Was the beacon Levels tag altered or changed, or am I just missing something really obvious? I *can* successfully test for the presence of a beacon, but not a particular level. The wiki says nothing about a change so maybe this is a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tag was indeed missing and a bug report can be found [here](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-147578). This bug was fixed in 1.14.1-pre1.